# Image Size in larger devices

Tags: android, image, resize, android-relativelayout

I have this image in my app, when I tested it in my Droid X and Droid bionic and other smaller devices, it looks fine. But when I tested it on my Android Tablet, the image was stretched. I just want to know if there is a proper way to solve this issue.

Note: I have tried adding the actual size of the image like 200dp by 300 dp. But it still don't work

Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout 
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/kittens"/>        

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the actual size of the `kittens` image?

Comment: It is acually 220 by 325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use wrap_content for ImageView, instead use dp like:

```
<ImageView
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="200dp"
         android:background="@drawable/kittens"/>
```

Comment: You have to find the correct width and height in dp on one screen size, then it will be correct for other screen sizes as well

Comment: The actual size of size of my image is 220 by 325. I just tried the code you told me using the real size of my image, the image was not stretched anymore but it became smaller and shows huge black empty space on the right side.

Comment: If it is smaller then try rising the width and height keeping the scale, the black empty space has to do with your layout not with the image

Comment: If I I try rising the width and height, then it will become larger in other smaller device

Comment: That's normal, try using different layouts for diffent screen sizes. layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi, layout-ldpi

Comment: I am really new at this, but where can I find the " layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi, layout-ldpi" should I create those and have a seperate layouts?

Comment: yes, u have to create them, do some searching to understand what it does